# How many employees worked each year?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have simple table Employee id, start year, end year. I have to find how many employees worked in min year to max year. if min year is 2000 and max. year sysdate it should listed all those years from 2000 to 2017 with number of worked employees

Comment: Could you please include a sample table or your schema so that we don’t have to guess what it looks like?

Comment: So you want one row with year 2000 and number of employees that year, one row year 2001 with number of employees that year, and so on? Do you have a table containing all the year numbers?

Comment: [link to the example table](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2z2BF4fbWh8aE1tMldQNG5CVDA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - scope of years need to be more dynamic - if the first employee start to work in 1990 then I need scope from 1990 to the actual date (year - SYSDATE)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it, but I am sure there are other better ways someone can show us.

```
with MA_MITARBEITER_TH (user_id, grp_type, sap_valid_from, sap_valid_to) as
(
  select 107,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '23-09-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 107,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2012','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 107,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '23-09-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 107,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-07-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-08-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 107,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-06-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 107,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2012','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 107,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-09-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-2011','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 107,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-04-2006','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-05-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 107,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-09-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '22-09-2011','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 106,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-02-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 106,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-02-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 106,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '15-05-2006','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-01-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-05-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-10-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2008','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-2008','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2009','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-06-2009','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2014','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '01-12-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-11-2016','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-10-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-03-2017','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-05-2017','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2017','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '28-02-2017','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2017','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '21-09-2006','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-05-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2008','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-06-2009','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-2012','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-03-2010','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-2012','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2012','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-2012','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-11-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-11-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-11-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-07-2009','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-07-2009','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-05-2008','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-08-2009','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '28-02-2010','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '02-12-2014','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '02-12-2014','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '02-12-2014','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-11-2016','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '02-12-2014','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-10-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2017','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2014','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-10-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2014','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-03-2010','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-2012','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 105,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '02-12-2014','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-10-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 104,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-09-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 104,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2009','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-06-2009','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 104,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2008','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-2008','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 104,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-09-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 104,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2010','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-08-2011','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 104,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-07-2009','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-2009','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 104,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-05-2008','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 104,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2010','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-09-2010','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 104,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2008','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-06-2009','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 104,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '10-04-2006','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-05-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '20-08-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-05-2008','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-08-2006','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-05-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2008','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-2008','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-06-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-08-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '19-08-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2009','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-06-2009','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-07-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-07-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-07-2009','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-05-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-09-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-11-2009','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-05-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-07-2009','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-10-2009','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-07-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '19-08-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '04-12-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '02-12-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2017','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '03-12-2016','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-11-2009','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2012','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-07-2009','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-07-2009','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-05-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-09-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '01-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '02-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '03-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '02-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '04-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '03-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '05-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '04-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '06-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '05-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '06-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '07-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '07-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '08-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '09-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '08-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '09-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '10-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '11-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '10-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '12-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '11-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '13-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '12-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '14-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '13-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '15-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '14-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '03-12-2016','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '02-12-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '03-12-2016','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 100,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '04-12-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '02-12-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 103,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-12-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 103,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '23-05-2006','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-05-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 103,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-11-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 103,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-12-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-12-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-12-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-12-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-12-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-08-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2012','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-08-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-08-2011','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-05-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-11-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '02-11-2008','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-2008','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2009','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-06-2009','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-11-2008','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-2008','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '13-12-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '14-12-2016','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2017','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-05-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-05-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2010','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-09-2010','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-12-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '27-05-2008','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-11-2008','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '01-11-2008','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2008','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-06-2008','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-07-2008','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-10-2008','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-10-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-07-2009','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-05-2010','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-11-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-11-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '02-11-2008','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-06-2009','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-10-2010','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-07-2011','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '28-05-2008','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-05-2008','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '02-12-2014','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '02-12-2014','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '13-12-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '14-12-2016','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-07-2006','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-04-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 102,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2017','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 101,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-09-2010','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 101,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-04-2009','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-06-2009','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 101,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2009','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-03-2009','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 101,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-01-2009','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '28-02-2009','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 101,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2008','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-2008','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 101,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-03-2009','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-06-2009','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 101,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-07-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '29-02-2008','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 101,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '27-05-2008','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-05-2008','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 101,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '27-03-2008','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '26-05-2008','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 101,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-04-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-05-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 101,   'NOT_ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-09-2010','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-12-9999','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 101,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-03-2008','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '26-03-2008','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 101,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2008','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '28-02-2009','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 101,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '23-10-1992','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-03-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 101,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-06-2007','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '30-06-2007','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  select 101,   'ACTIVE',   to_date( '01-07-2009','dd-mm-yyyy'),    to_date( '31-08-2010','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual
)
--select * from MA_MITARBEITER_TH;
,
-- uncomment the below line to point to your db
-- ;with 
emp (id, hired, fired) as
(
   select user_id, to_number(to_char(sap_valid_from, 'yyyy')), to_number(to_char(sap_valid_to,'yyyy')) 
   from
   (
      select user_id, min(sap_valid_from) sap_valid_from, max(sap_valid_to) sap_valid_to 
      from MA_MITARBEITER_TH 
      where grp_type = 'ACTIVE' 
      group by user_id
   )
)
--select * from emp;
,
-- grouping of hired by year
hy (year, cnt) as
(
  select hired, count(hired)
  from emp 
  group by hired 
)
,
-- grouping of fired by year
fy (year, cnt) as
(
  select fired, count(fired)
  from emp 
  group by fired
)
,
-- put them together with a cte
-- it takes care of years where no HR activity
-- anchor is set to the min hired year.
cte (year, hired, fired, emp_cnt) as 
(
  select hy.year, nvl(hy.cnt ,0), nvl(fy.cnt,0), hy.cnt - nvl(fy.cnt,0)  
  from hy 
       left outer join 
       fy 
       on hy.year = fy.year 
  where hy.year = (select min(year) from hy)
  union all
  select cte.year+1, nvl(hy.cnt,0), nvl(fy.cnt,0), cte.emp_cnt + nvl(hy.cnt,0) - nvl(fy.cnt,0)
  from cte 
       left outer join 
       hy 
       on (cte.year+1 = hy.year) 
       left outer join 
       fy 
       on (cte.year+1 =  fy.year) 
  where cte.year < to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy')
)
select * from cte;
  ;
```

Comment: I was thinking about more dynimic sql. Please see example table and comments above. Apart from that Im very greatful for your help!!

Comment: What does NOT_ACTIVE imply? Does it influence the reporting query? There are many duplicate rows like line 2 and 4. If the same USER_ID has multiple entries for a specific year, do you treat them as separate or the same in the additions?

Comment: In this case we need just select ACTIVE GROUP of entries for particular user_id and select min value from VALID_FROM and max. value from VALID_TO to check how long some employee was working (time scope) for company. Addition to that we just round all this value by extracting the YEAR from DATE (VALID_FROM, VALID_TO & SYSDATE as actual year = in this case I assumed that EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) should be handled as max year 2017=max and not 9999 as max;)

Comment: this is a list of years to count the number of employees for particular year: 
---LIST OF ALL YEARS
with YEARS as
(
SELECT MIN(SAP_VALIDFROM) AS SAP_VALID_FROM, MAX(SYSDATE) AS SAP_VALID_TO
FROM MA_MITARBEITER_TH
)
select (to_char(SAP_VALID_FROM,'YYYY') + level -1) AS YEARS
from YEARS
connect by level < = to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYY') - to_char(SAP_VALID_FROM,'YYYY')+1;

Comment: I have combine some other queris, but not sure 100% if this is really working:

Comment: so my edited sql didn't produce what you are looking for?

Comment: It is a great solution too, I have learned a lot from you approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I combined some queries and I'm thinking now that is what I wont, please check if this is issue-less solution:

`with YEARS as
(
select (to_char(SAP_VALID_FROM,'YYYY') + level -1) AS YEARS
from 
    (
    SELECT MIN(SAP_VALIDFROM) AS SAP_VALID_FROM, MAX(SYSDATE) AS SAP_VALID_TO
    FROM MA_MITARBEITER_TH
    ) YEARS
connect by level < = to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYY') - to_char(SAP_VALID_FROM,'YYYY')+1
),
YEARS_SCOPE AS
(
SELECT PERSONALNUMMER, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (MIN(SAP_VALIDFROM))) AS ARBEIT_BEGINN, 
CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (MAX(SAP_VALIDTO)))='9999' THEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (MAX(SYSDATE))) ELSE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (MAX(SAP_VALIDTO))) END AS ARBEIT_SCHLUSS
FROM MA_MITARBEITER_TH
WHERE TIMEGROUP='AKT'
GROUP BY PERSONALNUMMER
)
select COUNT(*), YEARS 
FROM YEARS,YEARS_SCOPE
WHERE YEARS BETWEEN ARBEIT_BEGINN AND ARBEIT_SCHLUSS
GROUP BY YEARS
ORDER BY YEARS;`